# Generating JSON from nested Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have the following Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<ChartData>>> data;
```

ChartData implementation looks like this:

```
   public struct ChartData
    {
        public long datetime;
        public double open;
        public double high;
        public double low;
        public double close;
        public ulong tick_volume;
        public int spread;
        public ulong volume;
    }
```

I want to generate JSON using the data I have in my data container. My data must look something like that:

```
{
    "EURUSD": [
        {
            "PROV": [
                {
                    "datetime":34534554,
                    "open":2.31,
                    "high":123,
                    "low":3213,
                    "close":213,
                    "tick_volume":2131,
                    "spread":2131,
                    "volume":3123
                },
                {
                    "datetime":34534554,
                    "open":2.31,
                    "high":123,
                    "low":3213,
                    "close":213,
                    "tick_volume":2131,
                    "spread":2131,
                    "volume":3123
                }
            ],
            "LMAX":[
                {
                    "datetime":34534554,
                    "open":2.31,
                    "high":123,
                    "low":3213,
                    "close":213,
                    "tick_volume":2131,
                    "spread":2131,
                    "volume":3123
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "BTCUSD":[
        {
            "PROV":[
                {
                    "datetime":34534554,
                    "open":2.31,
                    "high":123,
                    "low":3213,
                    "close":213,
                    "tick_volume":2131,
                    "spread":2131,
                    "volume":3123
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The solution I have right now is this:

```
   var jsonObjectData= JObject.Parse(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data));
    var result = new JObject();

    result.Merge(jsonObjectData);

    var json = result.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

But I don't see any correct data here.

Do you have any suggestions, that I could use to generate the required JSON from my nested Dictionary container ?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Example of the dictionary data?
Do you get any data parsed or nothing??

Comment: create the first levels of your datastructure (JObject) as a Dictionary<string, JToken>

Comment: @mapa0402 I get some data, but the data from ChartData is empty like { }

Comment: @J.Salas Could you give me an example ?

Comment: Why do use System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft's Json.NET at the same time? Why don't you use only one of them?

Answer (score 2):

Try using newtonsoft:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The major issue here is that by default, `System.Text.Json.Serializer` will **NOT** serialize fields. The solution from Amjad works because NewtonSoft serializes all fields and properties by default, *as long as they are `public`*.

The best practice advice for this is to **change your model** so that `ChartData` uses *properties* instead of *fields*:

```
public struct ChartData
{
    public long datetime { get;set; }
    public double open { get;set; }
    public double high { get;set; }
    public double low { get;set; }
    public double close { get;set; }
    public ulong tick_volume { get;set; }
    public int spread { get;set; }
    public ulong volume { get;set; }
}
```

Alternatively, if you do **not** want to use *properties* you can annotate the *fields* with the [`[JsonInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute) Attribute:

```
public struct ChartData
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public long datetime;
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public double open;
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public double high;
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public double low;
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public double close;
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public ulong tick_volume;
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public int spread;
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public ulong volume;
}
```

Either of those changes to the `ChartData` *struct* will include the content in the output of this code:

```
string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

---

There is another option, but it is widely considered an *Anti-Pattern*, that is to specify in the *options* that you want to include fields as well:

```
var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions  
              { 
                  WriteIndented = true,
                  IncludeFields = true  
              };
string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, options);
```

The `IncludeFields` setting is the *easy* option for this particular scenario as it doesn't require changes to the model, but doing this will include the fields of *ALL* nested objects that are being serialized, not just `ChartData`. This can lead to unexpected content being included. We recommend in .Net that you use `public` *properties* instead of *fields*, the reverse is also true, in class design, we expect that *fields* **WILL NOT** be included in serilization output.

The reasons and justifications on this are well understood and accepted by the .NET community so I won't go into detail here, but it is important to highlight again that you should respect the expected behaviours associated with *properties* and *fields* and that is why you should use *properties* or specifically annotate your *fields* to declare that you want the values to be included in serialization output.

> You do not want to get into the habit of using the `IncludeFields` option in all of your serialization routines, as different data type may exhibit very different outputs and this may even affect *deserialization* processes.

---

As [Amjab Saab has posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70865378/1690217) you could also use Newtonsoft's Newtonsoft's Json.NET instead of `System.Text.Json` however in this case the .NET team are specifically guiding us to design our classes better and are actively trying to enforce code standards and declarative design patterns, where *Newtonsoft's* approach is to be resilient to different design patterns agnostically. Due to this the .NET implementation is significantly faster and I encourage you to continue using `System.Text.Json`.

> Note that James Newton-King, the author of `Netwonsoft.Json` is a key engineer in the team responsible for `System.Text.Json`. Think of System.Text.Json as an evolution that specifically has performance and conformance to JSON specification as a key goals. read more here: [A Brief Comparison Between Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json](https://schneids.net/comparing-newtonsoft-json-with-system-text-json)

I have prepared a fiddle showing one difference between the two libraries: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MSO1iA

#### Result using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);

```
{
  "EURUSD": {
    "PROV": [
      {},
      {}
    ],
    "LMAX": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  "BTCUSD": {
    "PROV": [
      {}
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Result using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true });

```
{
  "EURUSD": {
    "PROV": [
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123,
        "low": 213,
        "close": 213,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      },
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123,
        "low": 3213,
        "close": 213,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      }
    ],
    "LMAX": [
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123,
        "low": 3213,
        "close": 213,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      }
    ]
  },
  "BTCUSD": {
    "PROV": [
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123,
        "low": 3213,
        "close": 213,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Result using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

*This is included as a comparison for devs who are just coming across to the current versions of .Net*

```
{
  "EURUSD": {
    "PROV": [
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123.0,
        "low": 213.0,
        "close": 213.0,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      },
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123.0,
        "low": 3213.0,
        "close": 213.0,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      }
    ],
    "LMAX": [
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123.0,
        "low": 3213.0,
        "close": 213.0,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      }
    ]
  },
  "BTCUSD": {
    "PROV": [
      {
        "datetime": 34534554,
        "open": 2.31,
        "high": 123.0,
        "low": 3213.0,
        "close": 213.0,
        "tick_volume": 2131,
        "spread": 2131,
        "volume": 3123
      }
    ]
  }
}
```